# $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq a_3 \geq \ldots, \sum a_n < \infty$ so $na_n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I’d like to proof if $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq a_3 \geq \ldots, \sum a_n < \infty$ so $na_n \rightarrow 0$.

We have that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ due to $\sum a_n < \infty$.

$ka_n=a_1+...+a_n$, $k$ times

$\lim (ka_n)=\lim(a_1)+\ldots+\lim(a_n)$

$\lim(ka_n)=0$

but I know for $k=n$ I can’t do the same, I couldn’t go further from above.

Comment: Notation: use `\cdots` for vertically centered items, e.g. $\lim a_1 + \cdots + \lim a_n$

Comment: Are you defining $k$ by the equation $ka_n = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$? I'm having trouble following your argument.

Comment: First of all, you can convince yourself that $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (use contradiction).Then, you have to realize that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\geq n a_n$  and the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $a_m > 0, \forall m \ge 1$. Put  $s_n = a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n$, the $s_n$ is the traditional partial sum of the $a_j$'s. We are given that $s_n$ converges since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$, hence it is a Cauchy sequence. Thus given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \ge 1$ such that if $n \ge N$ then: $|s_{2n} - s_n| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\implies a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots + a_{2n} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\implies na_{2n} < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}\implies 2na_{2n} < \epsilon$. This suffices to show that $na_n \to 0$ as claimed.

**Note:** The condition $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \infty$ cannot be included because for $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$ we have: $a_n > a_{n+1} > a_{n+2} > \cdots$, and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n} = \infty$, yet $na_n = 1 $ and does not converge to $0$.